# how to capture variables into the window.location.search when submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables

Ok, so I have a form, and here's what I want to do with it:

Upon submitting, (provided submission is successful):

- Capture the value of a specific input field 'x' in the form into a variable 'xval'
- Append the value of the variable 'xval' to the url
- And navigate to a specific page...

See, I have a few pages which are conditional in their content, depending on variables that I pass through the url... So the address on step 1 looks like this:

```
whatever.com/products.html?home?try
```

On step 2, which is the form, it looks like this"

```
whatever.com/products.html?home?try?5?john@gmail.com
```

Step 3, is supposed to read the url, and accordingly show information.

To reiterate, I don't know how to capture the variables and append them to the url when the user supposedly completes step 2...

I have tried a function on the submit button, that causes the navigation to trigger without submit validation... I tried the 'onsubmit' event handler on the form tag itself, and it didn't seem to work...

Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried setting the form up with `method="GET"`?

Comment: You can't have more than one question mark in the URL. If you do then I'm sure you will run into unexpected behaviours and cross browser difficulties... A querystring should be encoded as something more like `page=home&action=try&stage=5&email=john@gmail.com`

Comment: @Pointy - Nope, will have a go at it... @vitch - Really? I've been using it with multiple question marks and what not... But ok, thanks for the heads up...

Comment: @vitch - This is slightly off topic, but can you please explain to me how to pass variables your way? In my situation, I use the '?' as a splitter and capture different positions into different variables. Mind you, this is ONLY in js, no server side scripts...

Comment: @vitch - Ok, so I did some reading and I have a function that I got from bloggingdeveloper.com which allows me to capture values from the querystring, but how about setting them? Is it the mundane process of setting it like so - "window.location.href?page=' + source +&action=' + action + '&stage=' + stage + '&email=' + email";

Comment: If you aren't worried about serverside then you could just use an initial question mark and then any other symbol to split your values (e.g. `products.html?home&try&5&john@gmail.com` or `products.html?home|try|5|john@gmail.com`). A more complex solution to allow proper querystrings is shown in the deparam method of jQuery BBQ: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say: stick to the accepted way of defining form fields in a GET string (`?this=that&foo=bar`). This would be a way to load your page with new parameters:

```
var locationstr = location.href.split('?')[0], //URL without params
    try = document.getElementById('try_inputfield').value,
    email = document.getElementById('email_inputfield').value,
    newLocation = [locationStr,
                   '?home=1',
                    '&try=',
                     try,
                    '&email=',
                     email].join('');         // glue new parameters
location.replace(newLocation);                // replace location
```

if you want to read and use the properties as defined per `location.search` this is a string extension to convert the querystring into an object:

```
String.prototype.q2obj = function(){
    var qArr = this.split('&')
        ,qObj = {}
        ,i =-1;
    while(++i<qArr.length) {
            qfrag = qArr[i].split('=');
            qObj[qfrag[0]] = qfrag[1];
   }
   return qObj;
};
//usage
var queryObj = location.search.substr(1).q2obj();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the name attribute on your input components.  If your using a simple form submissions something like this should append the values to the url.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="txt-name" name="name"/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand, could you explain to me what's happening here and how you're going about solving my problem? I didn't know the html <button> tag had a 'type' attribute...

Comment: I'm not going to say it as well as others so start by reading this page: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Basically the submit button submits a new get request to the server.  The submit button also has a "method" attribute which can be used to specify that the action is a post.  When performing a new get request the form constructs the parameter string.  The parameter string is constructed by taking all of the name attributes and putting them in key value pairs.  The parameter string starts with a ? and then key value pairs are appended like key=value and are separated by & .  So a parameter string looks like ?key1=value1&key2=value2